# Change dynamic Height Constraint of Element inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITextView` inside a `UITableViewCell`.
It's not editable, data to textView loaded from `JSON` parsing, I use `UITextView` instead `UILabel` because I need some tap gestures on `NSAttributed Strings`, in a way that can't be done with `UILabel`.

For a row, that i want to present text on `UITextView` I need it visible having height constraint with constant 40.

For a row that i don't want to present text I need it hidden without height, so i make height constraint having 0 constant.

Problem is that although on that case `UITextView` can be hidden, it's height remains.

I use automatic dimensions for cell height.

Tried many ways that I found here on stackoverflow but unfortunately didn't solve my problem.

Just to note, it's not necessary to having a specific height for this `UITextView`. I just want it depending on data i receive, either to be visible without some height or hidden without any height.

[image]

Comment: Post the screenshot of issue . try google "self sizing cells uitableview"

Comment: just uploaded a simple image, showing what i mean, thx

Comment: You can use the `estimatedRowHeight` property on your `tableView` and set the value `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

Comment: kcpac i already tried that. Problem is that Cell's keeps  "consider" UITextView active whatever i do. Tried add and remove Height Constraints also, nothing changed.

Comment: you could try to set the `numberOfLines` to `0` and remove the height constraint from the label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hiding a subview does not remove it from the view hierarchy or layout calculations.

If you want to hide the `UITextView` and have the layout update correctly, there's two options I can think of.

If your targeting iOS >= 9, you should use a `UIStackView`. It automatically adjusts its layout when one of its subviews is hidden which is what you need.

Otherwise you would have to remove and create constraints so that bottom of the cell is constrained to the red view (in your image) instead of the `UITextView`.

Comment: Tried the UIStackView, but unfortunately nothing chaged. Second solution cant be done that way because I have more elements below that UITextView I want to hide. Speaking about the layout update I have tried setNeedsDisplay(), layoutSubviews(), tableView.beginUpdates() etc. What am I missing?

Comment: In your question, it isn't clear when you are trying to hide the UITextView. My answer works if your doing it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` but if your doing somewhere it it may not work. Maybe update your question with more details. I've used the second solution with ~10 views in the past before UIStackView was added. It doesn't end up being that much code.